# Dji Tello Grey Screen Python

Tags: python

I have a 3-meter model train track. And there are various objects on the train track. When my drone is not take off, it turns on the camera and detects the objects. When I code the drone for takeoff, the camera turns on but shows it as a gray screen. The camera turns on when the drone lands. So when the Drone moves, the camera does not show. What is the reason of this?

```
import cv2
import time

w,h= 1280,720

fly=1

myDrone = initializeTello()


while True:
    ##Step1
    img = telloGetFrame(myDrone, w, h)
    ##Step2
    img = findFaultyRail(img)
    cv2.imshow('Image', img)

    if fly == 1:
        myDrone.takeoff()
        time.sleep(8)
        myDrone.move_forward(100)
        time.sleep(3)
        myDrone.land()
        fly = 2


    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0x0FF == ord('q'):
        myDrone.land()
        break
```

[image]